# How to 'add watch' in Chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I can't seem to find a way to add a watch expression for the selected JavaScript text in Chrome developer tools, the same way I would in Firebug with Ctrl+W.  Is there really no way to do this in Chrome?  I can't even right-click the selection as it unselects as soon as I do it, and there is no "Add watch" context menu item.  Do I really have to type in every watch I want to add while debugging JS?

Comment: I think if you right click, you **will** get an option to add to watch

Comment: @ArinCool My Chrome seemed to have temporarily broken.  It was definitely deselecting when I right-clicked, but now it isn't.  Magic.

Comment: Aaaand now it's broken again, and I have to use `ctrl+shift+A` to add watch.  Each time I right click, the selected text is unselected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it by clicking '*add to watch*' **after** right clicking

You can also select the expression/variable and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: Weird.  Just after you posted this I tried again, and suddenly the right-click menu is working and *not* deselecting my text.  Also, Ctrl+Shift+A does work too.

Comment: @Jez Happy add-to-watching-day!

Answer (score 14):

From the Chrome DevTool docs on [JS Debugging Reference > Watch the values of custom JavaScript Expressions](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#watch), you can do it in 1 of 3 ways:

1. Highlight text, right click, and selct **`Add selected text to watches`**

   [image: Add selected text to watches]

   ***Note**: this used to be "Add to watch"
2. Highlight text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
3. Add expression on the watch panel directly in the top right corner of the sources tab

   [image: Add Watch Expression]

Answer (score 6):

You need to **double click** the variable name, **then right click** will reveal the add to watch option.