# Watch JavaScript function parameter value while debugging in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I do not have any option to update the javascripts loaded into the page by other applications. But I need to know the "*flagDisplaySpecialButton*" parameter value at runtime (debugging purpose only) when "*showSpecialButton*" function is called.

Is there any way to watch this variable while debugging in chrome browser?

```js
async function showSpecialButton(flagDisplaySpecialButton) {
  const specialButton = document.getElementById('specialButtonWrapper');
  const isSpecialButtonEligible = true; //await getSpecialButtonEligibility();
  if (specialButton) {
    if (isSpecialButtonEligible && flagDisplaySpecialButton) {
      specialButton.hidden = false;
      return true;
    }
    specialButton.hidden = true;
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}

showSpecialButton(true); //called from different javascript files
```

```html
<div id="specialButtonWrapper" hidden>
  <button id="specialButton">Special Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me know if this helps you - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/reference/#watch

Comment: Also this should help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/27247350/14569750

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to 'add watch' in Chrome developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247350/how-to-add-watch-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: Sure you should be able to see that value when debugging. Can you elaborate on how you are debugging that function? Did you set a breakpoint inside it?